# Matching regex without a certain word behind another word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have to match the word `'like'` without the word `'not'` before it. In the example below, there is a `'not'` before the word `'like'` so it shouldn't have matched it. How would I fix this?

```
$tempInput = "i do not like to fail";
if (preg_match("~(?!not )(like)~", $tempInput, $match)) {

print_r($match);

}
```

**Result:**

Array ( [0] => like [1] => like )

**Need Result:**

Null

Comment: From the word `like` do you need to look **behind** or **ahead** to check if there is no `not` there?

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind:

   `"~(?<!not )like~"` (or with word boundaries: `'~(?<!\bnot )\blike\b~'`)

Comment: @Rizier123 Just behind.

Comment: @frosty Exactly. And now what is: `(?!)`?

Comment: @Rizier123 It means 'not' right?

Comment: @frosty *Just behind* <- That is correct, now ask yourself what kind of lookaround you use here: `(?!not )`. Otherwise check with https://regex101.com

Comment: @Rizier123 Um, match anything that is not the word 'not'?

Comment: @frosty As you said *Just behind.* so you just want to look behind and make sure `not` can NOT be matched. Now right now you use `(?!)`. Now is this a positive or negative assertion and does it look behind or ahead? Check with https://regex101.com Put `(?!)` into it and look what you use right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `negative lookbehind` for literal string `not` like this will do.

**Regex:** `/(?<!not )like/`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!not )` will `look behind` and check if there is word `not`.
- `like` if it is not present then `like` will be matched.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJ8zO9/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little *regex magic*.

It's easy to restrict using a fixed width lookbehind assertion.
For example, noob's regex `(?<!not )like` matches `not  like` invalid form's
all day long (not good).

But this `(?<!not)(?<!\s)\s*\b(like)` will match as though a variable
length lookbehind is legal in php.

In an ideal world it would be this `(?<!not\s+)like` variable.

So, I leave this for anybody who wants wonder how it works.
The `like` word is always in capture group 1.

As a bonus the `like` group can be any regex sub-expression.

```
 (?<! not )        # Guard, Not 'not' behind
 (?<! \s )         # Guard, Not whitespace behind 
 \s*               # Optional whitespace that can't be backtracked
 \b                # Word boundary
 ( like )          # (1), 'like'
```